# Apache Airflow authentication through IdentityServer4(.NET)

Tags: airflow, identityserver4, flash-builder

I installed Airflow on a VM and trying to integrate Airflow with Identity Gateway Server. The server is an implementation of IdentityServer4 (https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I have created a client in the IdentityServer and trying to get help docs.

I did not find any references for this.

**** Updating after trying out Python Flask AppBuilder OAuth ****

I have followed the page https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#authentication-oauth

and configured related parameters here is my

```
    OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [{
    'name':'azure',
        'token_key':'access_token',
        'remote_app': {
            'api_base_url':'<gateway>/',
            'client_kwargs':{
                'scope': 'profile openid email'
            },
            'access_token_url':'<gateway>/connect/token',
            'authorize_url':'<gateway>/connect/authorize',
            'request_token_url': None,
            'client_id': 'AIRFLOW_DEMO_CLIENT',
            'client_secret': None,
        }
    }]
```

I am not sure if the name **azure** is right or not.

The good news is airflow is asking me to login through the IdentityServer login page and the problem is I am getting errors after passing authentication.

```
[2021-09-18 05:42:28,548] {app.py:1892} ERROR - Exception on /oauth-authorized/azure [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/azureuser/af_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/azureuser/af_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/azureuser/af_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/azureuser/af_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
File "/home/azureuser/af_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/azureuser/af_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/azureuser/af_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/views.py", line 655, in oauth_authorized
    resp = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].authorize_access_token()
File "/home/azureuser/af_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/integrations/flask_client/remote_app.py", line 74, in authorize_access_token
    params = self.retrieve_access_token_params(flask_req, request_token)
File "/home/azureuser/af_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/integrations/base_client/base_app.py", line 145, in retrieve_access_token_params
    params = self._retrieve_oauth2_access_token_params(request, params)
File "/home/azureuser/af_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/integrations/base_client/base_app.py", line 126, in _retrieve_oauth2_access_token_params
    raise MismatchingStateError()
authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.MismatchingStateError: mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.
```

Same error I am seeing on the web page (after redirected to a link)

Pasting the URL:

https://<my_ip>/oauth-authorized/azure?code=72165*****6196&scope=profile%20openid%20email&state=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi*****nPMa58&session_state=wrO1****dYhY.29**A01

I am trying to map user info from IdentityServer to Airflow.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow uses Flask Application Builder for authentication. You should check with Flask Application Builder how to integrate identity4. I guess the gateway  supports Oauth2 or OpenID one of those is likely your best choice.

https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried through OAuth and something started working and updated the description in this question.

Comment: After configuring OAuth parameters (As described in question), Airflow is opening up the IdentityServer page and I was able to finish the authentication. But, getting errors at redirecting phase. I saw the browser redirected to URL " *https://<my_ip>/login/* " and then to a dynamic link with some keys. And I got the error **"ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"**.